# Nested for loops pyramid

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a program with nested for loop to display the list below

```
1
2 4
3 6  9
4 8  12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

.

```
for i in range(0,10):
  for j in range(1):
    print(i)
  print()
```

I have tried several different add-ons to get at least the second row but best I got so far is

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Comment: I am really new to coding. I have just started with this study in the beginning of the month (September) so really fresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j*i, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: You are welcome! But its elementary programming problem. Plz try to solve it by yourself, use pen and paper.  If you try to solve this by others then your knowledge of problem solving will be ruin.
Happy Coding

Comment: Will def try it on my own
Thanks